# java: How can I iterate over a number and check to see if each digit is either even or odd and then only return either one true or false value?

Tags: java, loops

Can someone explain to me how I am able to turn this into a loop? (allDigitsOdd Method)

There should only be one true value returned or one false value returned by the end of the loop.

Check each digit of a number to see if it is odd or even. If the digit is odd then keep going on to the next digit. If the digit being checked is even then stop the loop and return one false value for the entire number. If all of the digits are odd then return true. How can I make this work for any number and not just the one in the example of what I am trying to convey below?

````
```java

public class oddOrEvenDigits {
   public static void main(String[] args) {

      boolean b1 = allDigitsOdd(73925);
      System.out.println(b1);
// correct output is false value



// create Method
  public static boolean allDigitsOdd(int n) {

// The integer is n but I am putting 73925 in place of n for the example of what I am trying to do

      // get the last digit of the number (n)
      (73925 example) % 10); // gives 5 as answer

      // check to see if the last digit of n (5 in example) is even or odd
      // if it is odd then keep going
      // if it is even then return false and stop loop

    (73925 / 10); // becomes 7392
    (7392 % 10); // gives 2 as answer

      // check to see if 2 is even or odd
      // if it is odd then keep going
      // if it is even then return false and stop the loop

      // check to see if the 2 is even or odd

      (7392 / 10); // becomes 739
      (739 % 10); // Output 9
      // check to see if 9 is even or odd
      // if it is odd then keep going
      // if it is even then return false and stop the loop

      (739 / 10); // becomes 73
      (73 % 10); // Output 3
      // check if 3 is odd or even
      // if it is odd then keep going
      // if it is even then return false and stop the loop

    (73 / 10); // becomes 7
     (7 % 10);// Output 7
      // check if 7 is odd or even
      // if 7 is odd then if all the previous numbers checked are also odd then return
      // true and stop the loop
      // if 7 is even then stop the loop

}

```
````

Comment: You'll probably need to cast the number into a String, then loop over each character in the string and cast it back to an Int and do your comparison

Comment: Looks like a school assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way.

```
int[] data = {23122, 20202,31753, 20209,99999};
for (int i : data) {
    System.out.println(i + " " +allDigitsOdd(i));
}
```

prints

```
23122 false
20202 false
31753 true
20209 false
99999 true
```

- iterate until the number == 0
- get the last digit by using remainder (%) via 10.
- Then test for evenness doing the same with 2.
- As soon as even is detected, return false
- else return true if loop finishes.

```
public static boolean allDigitsOdd(int n) {
     while (n != 0) {
         if ((n%10)%2 == 0) {
             return false;
         }
         // expose next digit
         n/=10;
     }   
     return true;
}
```